# Java: Save date time without time conversion

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, time, data-conversion

I am using spring boot and mysql.

At first, one of my time field using Date type and I gotta use the `@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern=Constant.DATE_TIME_FORMAT, timezone = "....")` to take care of the time conversion due to different timezone. And then I changed it from `Date` to `LocalDateTime` to ensure there's no time conversion and remove the `timezone` property from above annotation.

But I was wrong, in UAT enrivonment, the input data saved in UI(swagger) changed '12:00:00'  to '04:30:00' in database.

I then tried to test by adjusting time zone in my machine and also the current time zone in mysql server.
Here's the result after several attemps:

```
Back-end Timezone, Database Timezone | Result
```

1. BE: +8:00, DB: +5:00 | 12h -> 9h
2. BE: +0:00, DB: +5:00 | 12h -> 17h
3. BE: +8:00, DB: +0:00 | 12h -> 4h

The data type for table column is `time` because I just want to save and display time so it doesn't matter which date so I'm using `1970-01-01` as default date.

The problem is I dont want any of time conversion due to the difference between timezone for BE and DB, I want the data saved in database to be exact as the input time on UI (UI: 12h -> DB: 12h).

This is my field in entity:

```
@ApiModelProperty(example = "1970-01-01 12:00:00")
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern=Constant.DATE_TIME_FORMAT)
private LocalDateTime monStartTime;
```

Question: is there any way that can avoid time conversion despite the difference in timezone between BE and DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take String as datatype in Backend.

```
private Sting monStartTime;
```

No need to change in Database. Database column should be time as you already have that.

Try this. It will not convert your timezone.